# source .zshrc to set ROS environment don't take effect

Tags: ros, source

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello all,

part of the .zshrc file as following:

```
source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.zsh
source /home/adminyin/catkin_ws/devel/setup.zsh
source /home/adminyin/rosws/devel/setup.zsh
```

when source .zshrc at terminal, it does nothing

only source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.zsh or other .zsh file manually can take effect

could someone tell me what's wrong about this?

It was occured when I use qtcreator open my ROS package, but failed at the CMake execution step

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248929/source-.zshrc-to-set-ros-environment-don%27t-take-effect/) by [yin](https://answers.ros.org/users/25699/yin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2016-11-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yin](https://answers.ros.org/users/25699/yin/) on 2016-11-28**:
➜  ~ source ./.zshrc
➜  ~ printenv | grep ROS
ROS_DISTRO=indigo
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/adminyin/rosws/src:/opt/ros/indigo/share:/opt/ros/indigo/stacks

it was over write?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> it was over write?

Yes. By default, `setup.*` files will overwrite the environment set by the previous one you `source`d.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-11-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0